# Setting Avatar using asmack

Tags: android, asmack, vcf-vcard, avatar

I am making a chat application for android and i am using asmack. My question is how do i set v-card avatar using asmack. what i am doing is as follows but the avatar is not getting saved. when i retrive avatar i got null

```
public static void setAvatarInVCard(){

urldefault=new URL("https://s3.amazonaws.com/ksr/avatars/3075521/Avatar.small.jpg");

java.io.InputStream stream = urldefault.openStream();

byte[] avatar1 = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);

System.out.println("avatar length "+avatar1.length);

             VCard vCard = new VCard();
     vCard.setAvatar(avatar1, "avatar1/jpg");            
     vCard.save(MyService.getConnection());

}
```

when i logcat result using asmack what stanza it was sending is as follows and the ending tags were not present either.

```
PM SENT (1090972696): <iq id="7hY4J-7" from="111@192.168.1.7/Smack" type="set"><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'><PHOTO><BINVAL>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAICAgICAQICAgIDAgIDAwYEAwMDAwcFBQQGCAcJCAgHCAgJCg0LCQoMCggICw8LDA0ODg8OCQsQERAOEQ0ODg7/2wBDAQIDAwMDAwcEBAcOCQgJDg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg4ODg7/wAARCABQAFADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHQAAAgIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAABwgFBgMECQECAP/EAEIQAAEEAQMCBAMEBQcNAAAAAAECAwQFBgcREgAhCBMiMQkUQSMyUWEVFhhCkSQzNFNnccEXUmJyc4GDkqGisbXw/8QAGgEAAwADAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQYHAgQIA//EAC8RAAEDAgQEBAcAAwAAAAAAAAECAxEABAUhMUEGElGhExRhgSIjMnGx0fAHkfH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AGL8xe331f8AN0r3ioznKsU0VgwMYta6BJu5JiOoekrTPkN7buIjAIUlACdyt5RHBPZPqUD0z3SIeMS+xl3JsKxBcGvk5LwXayZC2kKltxWifJYQo+pKXHQpZA2BDXfseqdibhaslkGDUA4fYD
```

i also try sending the URL directly like this

```
vCard.setAvatar(urldefault);
```

but still avatar not getting saved the log-cat result is as follows.

```
    03-14 18:06:37.199: D/SMACK(3210): 06:06:37 PM SENT (1090973048): <iq id="5SfDm-9" from="111@192.168.1.7/Smack" type="set"><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
03-14 18:06:37.289: D/SMACK(3210): 06:06:37 PM RCV  (1090973048): <iq type="result" id="5SfDm-9" to="111@192.168.1.7/Smack"/>
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi Fallak, what´s the maximum size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is the size of this image , i think its supposed be well within a range of 1 mb (Guess approx) or less, because i face the same issue and i get XML Stanza is too big as a response and the connection breaks , im looking at options to minimize the bitmap size

Comment: i have already did. And yes the problem was with the size of the image. Thanks for the answer.